# Use one filfilled for several createAsyncThunk functions

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I have two `createAsyncThunk` - `signIn` and `signUp` is it possible to use one `fulfilled reducer` both? The reason is that `fulfilled reducer` same for `signIn and signUp`. Example:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
builder.addCase(signInUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
  state.isPending = false;
  state.email = payload.username;
  state.username = payload.username;
  state.first_name = payload.first_name;
  state.last_name = payload.last_name;
  state.title = payload.title;
  state.organization = payload.organization;
  state.isNew = payload.isNew;
  state.isPremium = payload.isPremium;
  state.id = payload.id;
  state.error = '';
  state.access_token = payload.access_token;
  localStorage.setItem(REFRESH_TOKEN, payload.refresh_token);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an obvious solution that I found after refactoring, you can pass `state` and `payload` to another function and it can set `state` as it would in `yourAsyncThunk.fulfilled`. Example:

```
    builder.addCase(signInUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      assignStateWithUser(state, payload);
    });
    builder.addCase(signUpUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      assignStateWithUser(state, payload);
    });
    builder.addCase(loadUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
      assignStateWithUser(state, payload);
    });

const assignStateWithUser = (state: initialStateUser, payload: User) => {
  state.email = payload.username;
  state.username = payload.username;
  state.first_name = payload.first_name;
  state.last_name = payload.last_name;
  state.title = payload.title;
  state.organization = payload.organization;

};
```

Types for state and payload:
`type initialStateUser = RequestPending & { error: string } & User;`

```
export interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  email: string;
  title: string;
  organization: string;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have utils for this purpose: [watch this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities#using-matchers-to-reduce-code-complexity-duplication-and-boilerplate)